# Is it possible to rename firebase database name?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We had created the multiple databases. Now, we need to rename the database that is used for testing purpose. So, Is it possible to rename ***check-12cc0-test*** database? Please check out the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change your project name from here

[image]

I have it in Spanish, but at the right of project overview, project configuration you should see the pencil to edit your project name.

Note **you can't** change your database name since it's the ID of the project, you will need to create a new one and delete the one you have to change the database name. You can only change your children and keys inside your database main tree node.

Since the id of the project can't change, this is what Firebase tells to us about it:

> ID of the project
>
> It is the **unique identifier** of your Firebase project. You can find it in the project URL: `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<projectId>`

Remember that for edit the nodes and keys you can't do it directly from Firebase, instead you should export your JSON Database and edit it, then reupload it, or do it programmatically.

Comment: I want to rename the **database** not the *project-name*. INCORRECT ANSWER.

Comment: I answered that to you, read carefully , I just added how to edit your project name also